# URI schemes for Add new and Edit contact in windows phone 8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8, uri, contacts

I am a newbie in windows phone programming. I am looking for a way to call "Add new contact" and "Edit contact" by clicking a button. One solution for this is used `Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri(“ms-settings-bluetooth:”));`. However in this list of URI schemes (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj662937(v=vs.105).aspx) , there is no thing what I am looking for.

Anyone has another solution for this? Or you know the related URI schemes for adding and editing contact?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a new contact you don't need a Uri scheme as its actually a Phone Task.

For windowsphone os 8 and below there is a specific library to implement all such functions as Microsoft.Phone.Tasks

Your contact Add problem solution example can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh394013(v=vs.105).aspx)

Comment: Thanks so much @aman. I do not have enough reputation for voting up your answer. Anw, Thanks again.

Comment: Your solution is just for Windows phone 8 (silverlight). In my project, I am using windows 8.1 with Xaml. I found the solution for editing contacts by using this ```Windows.ApplicationModel.Contacts.ContactManager.ShowContactCard```.